# Custom command definition in magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I created a custom command in a magnolia custom module using:

```
public class ExportToGitCommand extends BaseRepositoryCommand
```

and I configure it in JCR manually at the moment.

What is the best practice regarding the definition of a custom command in a custom module?
Where in the JCR structure should one define it? I am asking this so that I can use it later (eg. for the pages app).
Also how can I get the definition from JCR programatically in the custom module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best practices, best place to look at is the [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Commands). Typically, each module creates its own command catalogue (folder) to ensure there's no collision in name of commands and store custom commands it defines under such catalogue.

To use such command from an action in other app you just create new action in the desired app and reference the custom command you want to call.

Comment: Thank you @Jan. 
How can I programatically add the definition of the command in JCR from `modules/myModule/commands/myCatalog/myCommands` to my module? This is so that this definition gets programatically added when we upgrade Magnolia.

Comment: you can just export configuration and put it in `mgnl-bootstrap` of your module. Then it would be installed automatically when module gets installed or you could force the installation on update of the module by using `BootstrapSingleResource` or `BootstrapSingleModuleResource` or similar install task.

Comment: Thanks @Jan for your answer.